# Selecting value of child element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Why is `<xsl:value-of select="p"/>` not resulting in the output of the XML source’s `p` element?

Also, how can I prevent `xmlns=""` from appearing on the result’s `trans-unit` elements?

Thanks.

### Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
]>
<svg>
<variableSets  xmlns="&ns_vars;">
    <variableSet  varSetName="binding1" locked="none">
        <variables>
            <variable  category="&ns_flows;" trait="textcontent" varName="Variable1"></variable>
            <variable  category="&ns_flows;" trait="textcontent" varName="Variable2"></variable>
            <variable  category="&ns_flows;" trait="textcontent" varName="Variable3"></variable>
            <variable  category="&ns_flows;" trait="textcontent" varName="Variable4"></variable>
        </variables>
        <v:sampleDataSets  xmlns:v="&ns_vars;" xmlns="&ns_custom;">
            <v:sampleDataSet  dataSetName="English">
                <Variable1>
                    <p>Introduction</p>
                </Variable1>
                <Variable2>
                    <p>STEP</p>
                </Variable2>
                <Variable3>
                    <p>3</p>
                </Variable3>
                <Variable4>
                    <p>Anonymous Answer</p>
                </Variable4>
            </v:sampleDataSet>
        </v:sampleDataSets>
    </variableSet>
</variableSets>
</svg>
```

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:v = "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="v">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="file"/>
    <xsl:param name="source-lang" select="'en-GB'"/>
    <xsl:param name="target-lang"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
            <file original="{$file}" source-lanuage="{$source-lang}" target-language="{$target-lang}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//v:sampleDataSet/*"/>
            </file>
        </xliff>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//v:sampleDataSet/*">
        <trans-unit id="{local-name()}">
            <source xml:lang="{$source-lang}"><xsl:value-of select="p"/></source> <!-- no value output -->
            <target xml:lang="{$target-lang}"></target>
        </trans-unit>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file original="ig-001" source-lanuage="en-GB" target-language="de-DE">
    <trans-unit xmlns="" id="Variable1">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB"/>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit xmlns="" id="Variable2"> <!-- unwanted xmlns attribute -->
      <source xml:lang="en-GB"/> <!-- output needed here -->
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit xmlns="" id="Variable3">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB"/>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit xmlns="" id="Variable4">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB"/>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

### Desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file original="ig-001" source-lanuage="en-GB" target-language="de-DE">
    <trans-unit id="Variable1">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB">Introduction</source>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit id="Variable2">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB">STEP</source>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit id="Variable3">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB">3</source>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit id="Variable4">
      <source xml:lang="en-GB">Anonymous Answer</source>
      <target xml:lang="de-DE"/>
    </trans-unit>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

### Solution

`p` element value: as per @LarsH’s answer, it was a namespace issue. I added the `xmlns:custom = "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/"` declaration to my `xsl:stylesheet` element and used `custom:p` instead of `p`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="custom:p"/>
```

`xmlns=""`: setting the default namespace with an `xmlns` attribute on the `xsl:stylesheet` element instead of manually on the root element handles this.

New XSLT in full:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
    xmlns:vars = "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/"
    xmlns:custom = "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="vars custom">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="file"/>
    <xsl:param name="source-lang" select="'en-GB'"/>
    <xsl:param name="target-lang"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xliff version="1.2">
            <file original="{$file}" source-lanuage="{$source-lang}" target-language="{$target-lang}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//vars:sampleDataSet/*"/>
            </file>
        </xliff>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//vars:sampleDataSet/*">
        <trans-unit id="{local-name()}">
            <source xml:lang="{$source-lang}"><xsl:value-of select="custom:p"/></source>
            <target xml:lang="{$target-lang}"></target>
        </trans-unit>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're asking two questions here. You might get better results asking one at a time.

Comment: Regarding 'how can I prevent xmlns="" from appearing on the result’s trans-unit elements', it depends: Do you want those result elements to be in no namespace, or in the oasis xliff namespace? Are you wanting to remove the `xmlns=""` because it's ugly, or because you think it causes `<trans-unit>` to be in the wrong namespace?

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: @LarsH, because it's ugly and I wasn't completely sure it being there wouldn't be a problem when the output XML is used elsewhere. `trans-unit` should be in the oasis namespace.

Comment: OK I'll update my answer to answer your 2nd question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is `<xsl:value-of select="p"/>` not resulting in the output of the XML source’s p element?

In this template

```
<xsl:template match="//v:sampleDataSet/*">
    <trans-unit id="{local-name()}">
        <source xml:lang="{$source-lang}"><xsl:value-of select="p"/></source>
```

the context node is any child of `<v:sampleDataSet>`, such as `<Variable1>`. In the source XML, the latter has `<p>` element children that are in the namespace identified by the URI `http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/`. This is because `<p>` has no namespace prefix, so it uses the default namespace, which is established by the nearest ancestor that has a default namespace declaration. This is

```
<v:sampleDataSets  ... xmlns="&ns_custom;">
```

However the XSLT is asking for `p` elements in no namespace. Hence the lack of any output.

> Also, how can I prevent xmlns="" from appearing on the result’s trans-unit elements?

You can't necessarily guarantee how namespace declarations will appear in the serialized output. However, you can specify what namespace each element will be in. Since you want the `<trans-unit>` elements to be in the oasis namespace, you need to specify that in your XSLT; and since they already have an ancestor in the output XML that has the oasis namespace as the default namespace, they may well get serialized with no namespace prefix and no namespace declaration attribute. You can tell XSLT to output the `<trans-unit>` elements in the oasis namespace the same way you did with the `<xliff>` elements:

```
   <trans-unit xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" id="{local-name()}">
```

That will put your trans-unit elements into the correct namespace in the result XML, which is the important thing for any downstream processing (and which isn't correct at the moment). Hopefully the namespace declarations in the result XML will also look nice, but that's not really guaranteed. However, there are details about placing namespace nodes that I don't remember, so maybe someone else can give a better answer on that.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd tried `v:p` but now I see that is not the namespace of of the `p` element.

Comment: Thanks also for the namespace declaration help. I did some reading on namespaces and now realise that declaring the default namespace in the `xsl:stylesheet` element instead of manually setting it as an attribute on the root element is the simplest way: `xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"`.